# vectorise foor loop with a variable that is incremented in each iteration

Tags: matlab, loops, for-loop, optimization, octave

I am trying to optimise the running time of my code by getting rid of some for loops. However, I have a variable that is incremented in each iteration in which sometimes the index is repeated. I provide here a minimal example:

```
a = [1 4 2 2 1 3 4 2 3 1]
b = [0.5 0.2 0.3 0.4 0.1 0.05 0.7 0.3 0.55 0.8]
c = [3 5 7 9]

for i = 1:10
    c(a(i)) = c(a(i)) + b(i)
end
```

Ideally, I would like to compute it by writting:

```
c(a) = c(a) + b
```

but obviously it would not give me the same results since I have to recalculate the value for the same index several times so this way to vectorise it would not work.
Also, I am working in Matlab or Octave in case that this is important.

Thank you very much for any help, I am not sure that it is possible to be vectorise.

---

**Edit**: thank you very much for your answers so far. I have discovered accumarray, which I did not know before and also understood why changing the for loop between Matlab and Octave was giving me such different times. I also understood my problem better. I gave a too simple example which I thought I could extend, however, what if b was a matrix?

(Let's forget about c at the moment):

```
a = [1 4 2 2 1 3 4 2 3 1]
b =[0.69  -0.41  -0.13  -0.13  -0.42  -0.14  -0.23  -0.17   0.22  -0.24;
   0.34  -0.39  -0.36   0.68  -0.66  -0.19  -0.58   0.78  -0.23   0.25;
  -0.68  -0.54   0.76  -0.58   0.24  -0.23  -0.44   0.09   0.69  -0.41;
   0.11  -0.14   0.32   0.65   0.26   0.82   0.32   0.29  -0.21  -0.13;
  -0.94  -0.15  -0.41  -0.56   0.15   0.09   0.38   0.58   0.72   0.45;
   0.22  -0.59  -0.11  -0.17   0.52   0.13  -0.51   0.28   0.15   0.19;
   0.18  -0.15   0.38  -0.29  -0.87   0.14  -0.13   0.23  -0.92  -0.21;
   0.79  -0.35   0.45  -0.28  -0.13   0.95  -0.45   0.35  -0.25  -0.61;
  -0.42   0.76   0.15   0.99  -0.84  -0.03   0.27   0.09   0.57   0.64;
   0.59   0.82  -0.39   0.13  -0.15  -0.71  -0.84  -0.43   0.93  -0.74]
```

I understood now that what I would be doing is rowSum per group, and given that I am using Octave I cannot use "splitapply". I tried to generalise your answers, but accumarray would not work for matrices and also I could not generalise @rahnema1 solution. The desired output would be:

```
[0.34   0.26  -0.93  -0.56  -0.42  -0.76  -0.69  -0.02   1.87  -0.53; 
 0.22  -1.03   1.53  -0.21   0.37   1.54  -0.57   0.73   0.23  -1.15;
-0.20   0.17   0.04   0.82  -0.32   0.10  -0.24   0.37   0.72   0.83;
 0.52  -0.54   0.02   0.39  -1.53  -0.05  -0.71   1.01  -1.15   0.04]
```

that is "equivalent" to

```
[sum(b([1 5 10],:))
 sum(b([3 4 8],:))
 sum(b([6 9],:))
 sum(b([2 7],:))]
```

Thank you very much, If you think I should include this in another question instead of adding the edit I will do so.

Comment: "working in MATLAB or Octave in case that this is important." Yes, it is. If you're using MATLAB, your code is faster than either of the vectorized solutions below, and rahnema1's answer doesn't work without modifications. In Octave, one of those solutions will likely be the fastest. I've posted timings for MATLAB in a comment under Luis' answer. -- You should always time your code, don't assume something is faster because it is vectorized or because it looks fast. On the other hand, if this code is not time critical, use the version that is easiest to read.

Comment: In general you should create a new question, because it is a substantial change. Anyway, what you want can be done with `full(sparse(repmat(a, 1, size(b,1)), repelem(1:size(b,2), size(b,1)), b))` or `accumarray([repmat(a, 1, size(b,1)).' repelem(1:size(b,2), size(b,1)).'], b(:))`. I have edited my answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Original question

It can be done with [`accumarray`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html):

```
a = [1 4 2 2 1 3 4 2 3 1];
b = [0.5 0.2 0.3 0.4 0.1 0.05 0.7 0.3 0.55 0.8];
c = [3 5 7 9];
c(:) = c(:) + accumarray(a(:), b(:));
```

This sums the values from `b` in groups defined by `a`, and adds that to the original `c`.

### Edited question

If `b` is a matrix, you can use

```
full(sparse(repmat(a, 1, size(b,1)), repelem(1:size(b,2), size(b,1)), b))
```

or

```
accumarray([repmat(a, 1, size(b,1)).' repelem(1:size(b,2), size(b,1)).'], b(:))
```

Comment: Worth pointing out this isn't true vectorisation though.

Comment: @Tasos Huh? `accumarray` is one the fastest Matlab functions, and it certainly qualifies as vectorization. Of courser it will have loops _inside_, but those loops are in C or some other lower-level, fast language. On the other hand, there are functions like `arrayfun` and `cellfun`, which _are_ essentially the same as Matlab loops. But `accumarray` is as vectorized as it gets

Comment: I'm not saying the function is not _optimised_. But it's not a reinterpretation of the problem in terms of simple vector operations (e.g. like rahnema's answer). I guess you're right that maybe the distinction is not as important though.

Comment: Obligatory benchmark: OP's code: 6.5e-7, Luis' code: 1.9e-6, rahnema1's code (sparse): 2.7e-6. For a larger test set (`c` is 100 elements, `a` and `b` are 1e6 elements), these times are respectively 0.0052, 0.0077, 0.1141. Thus, the plain old loop is the fastest for both large and small arrays (MATLAB R2017a). And it's  the easier by far to read.

Comment: Octave timings (using octave-online.net), for the larger set: 12.05, 0.0085, 0.1843. Didn't time the smaller set because Octave doesn't do `timeit`, and `tic`/`toc` are not meaningful for tiny times. When using Octave, it's definitely worth while to vectorize. It's like being back in the 90's with MATLAB! Also, Octave's `accumarray` is definitely vectorized (@Tasos).

Comment: @CrisLuengo that was kinda my point about the for loop too though. I'm sure the for loop in matlab is already pretty optimised. Vectorisation is _an_ optimisation method, but I wouldn't claim that optimization ≡ vectorization. E.g. if I wrote a mex function to make it even faster, I wouldn't call _that_ vectorisation. I'm sure accumarray is _optimised_ in some manner, I have no idea if this optimisation is obtained via simple vectorised operations under the hood or not. But on the shallow end of the definition it's not visibly a sequence of simple vector operations. Obviously definitions vary.

Comment: @Tasos: I thought you meant that `accumarray` is implemented in M-code as a loop or something like that. // I think of “vectorized” as calling one function that operates on the whole array, rather than looping over the elements of the array. I don’t make judgements about the simplicity of the vector operations. This is just slightly more complex than `sum`.

Comment: @CrisLuengo well we sort of agree then, it comes down to definitional semantics (which I still find an interesting topic, but probably less relevant here). `sum` was going to be my next example of the kind of function I consider "optimised" rather than "vectorised". For me a vectorised function is one that is an optimised extension of a scalar function to vector arguments. So, `plus` is vectorised. Whereas `sum` is simply a function that expects an array as its primary argument, and may or may not be optimised under the hood (and that optimisation may or may involved vectorised operations).

Comment: This may sound like hair-splitting, but my point was, OP never said anything about optimisation (though it may have been implied). She just asked if there's a vectorised syntax for this, that could transform the for loop into "something more 'vectorised' like c(a) = c(a) + b". I agree that accumarray is an elegant solution, but I'm not sure it answers the 'vectorised version' question. (which, again, may or may not have been exactly what OP was asking).

Comment: @Tasos, OP explicitly stated they wanted to optimize the running time of their code. No matter how you define “vectorize”, people learn that removing loops from MATLAB code is called “vectorizing”.

Comment: @CrisLuengo hahah, whoops, you're right, I totally missed the first sentence :facepalm:, thanks for setting me straight! You're right about what people learn, of course. But people still also learn that "matlab for loops are always slower". Doesn't mean we should just nod along to such aphorisms when there's room for constructive discussion. :)

Comment: @Tasos, I’ll certainly agree to that last statement!

Answer (score 4):

Matrix multiplication and implicit expansion and  can be used (Octave):

```
nc = numel(c);
c += b * (1:nc == a.');
```

For input of large size it may be more memory efficient to use sparse matrix:

```
nc = numel(c);
nb = numel(b);
c += b * sparse(1:nb, a, 1, nb, nc);
```

`Edit`: When `b` is a matrix you can extend this solution as:

```
nc = numel(c);
na = numel(a);
out = sparse(a, 1:na, 1, nc, na) * b;
```

Comment: Interestingly, the sparse version is faster on MATLAB R2017a, even for OP's small example data. See my comment on Luis' post for timings. Spoiler: OP's loop is fastest.

Comment: That is a great solution, and thanks to you now I understand my problem better. I have edited the question.

Comment: @AuroraGonzálezVidal I edited the answer for the case of matrix input.